# FFMPEG and Python: Stream a frame into video

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, pipe

#### Old approach

I have created a small class for the job. After the streaming of the third frame I get an error from FFMPEG:

`pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input`

and then I get a broken pipe.

I have  a feeling my ffmpeg input arguments are incorrect, I have little experience with the tool. Here is the code:

```py
import subprocess
import os
import cv2
import shutil
class VideoUpdater:
    def __init__(self, video_path: str, framerate: int):
        assert video_path.endswith(".flv")
        self._ps = None

        self.video_path = video_path
        self.framerate = framerate
        self._video = None
        self.curr_frame = None
        if os.path.isfile(self.video_path):
            shutil.copyobj(self.video_path, self.video_path + ".old")
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video_path + ".old")
            while cap.isOpened():
                ret, self.curr_frame = cap.read()
                if not ret:
                    break
                if len(self.curr_frame.shape) == 2:
                    self.curr_frame = cv2.cvtColor(self.curr_frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
                self.ps.stdin.write(self.curr_frame.tobytes())

    @property
    def ps(self) -> subprocess.Popen:
        if self._ps is None:
            framesize = self.curr_frame.shape[0] * self.curr_frame.shape[1] * 3 * 8
            self._ps = subprocess.Popen(
                f"ffmpeg  -i pipe:0 -vcodec mpeg4 -s qcif -frame_size {framesize} -y {self.video_path}",
                shell=True,
                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                stdout=sys.stdout,
            )
        return self._ps

    def update(self, frame: np.ndarray):
        if len(frame.shape) == 2:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
        self.curr_frame = frame
        self.ps.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())
```

and here is a script I use to test it:

```py
    import os
    import numpy as np
    import cv2

    size = (300, 300, 3)
    img_array = [np.random.randint(255, size=size, dtype=np.uint8) for c in range(50)]

    tmp_path = "tmp.flv"
    tmp_path = str(tmp_path)
    out = VideoUpdater(tmp_path, 1)

    for i in range(len(img_array)):
        out.update(img_array[i])
```

### Update closer to what I want

Having further studied how ffmpeg internals work, I went for an approach without pipes, where a video of a frame is made and appended to the .ts file at every update:

```py
import tmpfile
import cv2
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import subprocess
import shutil
import os


class VideoUpdater:
    def __init__(self, video_path: str, framerate: int):
        if not video_path.endswith(".mp4"):
            LOGGER.warning(
                f"File type {os.path.splitext(video_path)[1]} not supported for streaming, switching to ts"
            )
            video_path = os.path.splitext(video_path)[0] + ".mp4"

        self._ps = None
        self.env = {
        }
        self.ffmpeg = "ffmpeg "
        self.video_path = video_path
        self.ts_path = video_path.replace(".mp4", ".ts")
        self.tfile = None
        self.framerate = framerate
        self._video = None
        self.last_frame = None
        self.curr_frame = None

    def update(self, frame: np.ndarray):
        if len(frame.shape) == 2:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        else:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        self.writeFrame(frame)

    def writeFrame(self, frame: np.ndarray):
        tImLFrame = NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png")
        tVidLFrame = NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".ts")

        cv2.imwrite(tImLFrame.name, frame)
        ps = subprocess.Popen(
            self.ffmpeg
            + rf"-loop 1 -r {self.framerate} -i {tImLFrame.name} -t {self.framerate} -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y {tVidLFrame.name}",
            env=self.env,
            shell=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        )
        ps.communicate()
        if os.path.isfile(self.ts_path):
            # this does not work to watch, as timestamps are not updated
            ps = subprocess.Popen(
                self.ffmpeg
                + rf'-i "concat:{self.ts_path}|{tVidLFrame.name}" -c copy -y {self.ts_path.replace(".ts", ".bak.ts")}',
                env=self.env,
                shell=True,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            )
            ps.communicate()
            shutil.move(self.ts_path.replace(".ts", ".bak.ts"), self.ts_path)

        else:
            shutil.copyfile(tVidLFrame.name, self.ts_path)
        # fixing timestamps, we dont have to wait for this operation
        ps = subprocess.Popen(
            self.ffmpeg
            + rf"-i {self.ts_path} -fflags +genpts -c copy -y {self.video_path}",
            env=self.env,
            shell=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        )
        tImLFrame.close()
        tVidLFrame.close()
```

As you may notice, a timestamp correction needs to be performed.  By reading the final mp4 file, I saw however that it consistently has 3 fewer frames than the ts file, the first 3 frames are missing. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening